# Programmatically switch to developer mode in Android

Tags: android

I want to create a tool that allows to switch to developer mode on Android devices with an Android version less than 4.2. I want to create an apk to activate and deactivate the developer mode. Is this possible? How?

Comment: Phone -> settings -> Applications -> Development , You have options here to choose between developer and normal user. Why do you want to create a app for it

Comment: thanks,but i mentioned i need to do this using an apk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Developer" mode is a system setting and therefore can only be modified from a system application (i.e. signed with a manufacturer's key).  You cannot create an app that would modify this setting.