# Programmatically change device developer options on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-application

I'm playing around with android studio and I'm curious to see if it is possible access and change the developer options on my device when running my own app.

Specifically I'm interested in changing the "Simulate color space" options.
The values I can set by going to developer options are:

1. Deactivated
2. Monochromacy
3. red-green
4. blue-yellow

Does anyone have any experience changing these settings (or other similiar settings) with java using android studio?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is impossible due to security resons

Answer (score 3):

According to [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44618412/490114) you can check the current state of inversing display colors and of high contrast.

But changing any developer options is not allowed unless yours is a system app, see [Programmatically switch to developer mode in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897192/programmatically-switch-to-developer-mode-in-android)

If you really want it, you'll probably have to apply a theme for your app with specially selected colors.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59284223/6140277), which solves this for you.

This does require either **ROOT**, or permissions to be granted via **ADB** (see answer).

All the best, Tom.