# Android check if user is currently using greyscale mode

Tags: android

Simply, I need to check whether or not the device has color correction > greyscale  currently on.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

```
if (Settings.System.getInt(
            getContentResolver(),
            "accessibility_display_daltonizer_enabled",
            0
        ) == 0
) {

        println(" Greyscale mode is not enabled")
} else {

        println("Greyscale mode is enabled")

}
```

These are values for the other screen-space modes:

> DISABLED = -1
>
> MONOCHROMACY = 0
>
> PROTANOMALY = 11
>
> CORRECT_DEUTERANOMALY = 12
>
> TRITANOMALY= 13

Find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265519/programmatically-change-simulate-color-space-and-other-developer-options)